# How to handle too large requestUri for SOCRATA restful calls?

Tags: c#, rest, httpresponse, restful-url, socrata

I am using a RESTful call to a socrata data portal to fetch data.

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();            
client.BaseAddress = new Uri(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["APIEndPointHost"]);
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
string userName = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserName"];
string password = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PassWord"];
string credentials = userName + ":" + password;
var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(credentials);
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray));
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-App-Token", WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AppToken"]);

 HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
string searchCondition = "resource/xxxx-xxxx.json?$where=column1='something'AND column2='something';
 response = client.GetAsync(searchCondition).Result;
```

The problem is that sometimes the 'searchCondition ' can be very large say over 5000 characters, then I get the following errors while executing it.

> An error occurred while sending the request.
>
> The server committed a protocol violation. Section=ResponseStatusLine

Is this happening because of I am sending a big requestUri or does this have something do with socrata restricting the search condition limit?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about `Socrata`, but most clients and servers have a cap on the length of the URL. I think that 8k is the biggest I've seen. In some cases it's configurable, but usually it's a hard limit.

If you need your search conditions to be that large, you're going to have to use a POST. Can users save these search conditions? Use `POST /search-criteria` followed by `GET /resource?search-criteria={id}`. Alternately, you can make your search a POST request, but that's an inferior solution unless you Really, Truly need there to be only one request to the server.

Comment: Correct Eric, the length of a SoQL query will be limited by both the HTTP RFC and how long of a URI your HTTP library will handle. Unfortuantely we don't support sending larger queries as a POST, so you'll need to simplify or break up your SoQL query to fit within those limits.